# Passing a function to a function in matlab

Tags: function, matlab

How can I pass a function into another in matlab:

For example assume this function works as optimizer :

```
    Function [returnValue]=optimizer(@myfunction)
    %function definition
    End
```

How can I call optimizer function to optimize myfunction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
function optimizer(f)
...
x=0;
y=f(x);
...
end
```

And you call it like that:

```
f=@(x) (x^2); 
optimizer(f)
```

Answer (score 8):

Matlab has [function handles](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html) which enables you to pass function pointers around.